# numpy 2d array operation, keeping certain positions

Tags: python, numpy, 2d, where-clause

I have two 2d numpy arrays:

```
X2d = np.array([[0,4,5,0],
                [7,8,4,3],
                [0,0,9,8]])

Y2d = np.array([[1,0,4,8],
                [0,3,8,5],
                [0,6,0,8]])

#and I would like to get these two:

X2dresult = np.array([[0,0,5,0],
                      [0,8,4,3],
                      [0,0,0,8]])

Y2dresult = np.array([[0,0,4,0],
                      [0,3,8,5],
                      [0,0,0,8]])
```

So basically I need to keep those positions where both of the matrices are greater than 0. Can I use numpy.where function or something like that to get these results?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bitwise AND or OR and [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
>>> X2d = np.array([[0,4,5,0],
...                 [7,8,4,3],
...                 [0,0,9,8]])
>>> 
>>> Y2d = np.array([[1,0,4,8],
...                 [0,3,8,5],
...                 [0,6,0,8]])
>>> indices = np.where(~((X2d > 0) & (Y2d > 0)))
>>> X2d[indices] = 0
>>> Y2d[indices] = 0
>>> X2d
array([[0, 0, 5, 0],
       [0, 8, 4, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 8]])
>>> Y2d
array([[0, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 3, 8, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 8]])
```

I think bitwise `OR` is better and clearer to read:

```
>>> X2d = np.array([[0,4,5,0],
...                 [7,8,4,3],
...                 [0,0,9,8]])
>>> 
>>> Y2d = np.array([[1,0,4,8],
...                 [0,3,8,5],
...                 [0,6,0,8]])
>>> indices = np.where((X2d == 0) | (Y2d == 0))
>>> X2d[indices] = 0
>>> Y2d[indices] = 0
>>> X2d
array([[0, 0, 5, 0],
       [0, 8, 4, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 8]])
>>> Y2d
array([[0, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 3, 8, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X2dresult = ((X2d > 0) & (Y2d > 0)) * X2d
Y2dresult = ((X2d > 0) & (Y2d > 0)) * Y2d
```

Let `Z = ((X2d > 0) & (Y2d > 0))`, Then `Z[i,j] = True` if and only if `X2d[i,j] > 0` and `Y2d[i,j] > 0`

Now `X2dresult = Z * X2d`, So `X2dresult[i,j] = Z[i,j] * X2d[i,j]`, which is 0 if `Z[i,j] = False` and `X2d[i,j]` if `Z[i,j] = True`. (because `int(True) = 1` and `int(False) = 0`)

So, in `X2dresult` array all elements are `0` in those position where either `X2d` or `Y2d` has `0`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Currently, it's auto-flagged as low quality post.